# Install MongoDB and give access only to groups in Linux Ubuntu Server

Tags: mongodb, terminal, ubuntu-12.04

I have created a user group and I would like to know how can I install MongoDB on Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS such that only read/write access is given to certain users in a user group. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The users you define on the OS side has nothing to do with the users inside Mongodb, take a look at this http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/access-control/. You need to setup users inside the db itself to restrict access. You can check the security related topics [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/security-introduction/), that documentation contains detailed description of the concepts and explanation how to do the setup.